# How to save a class instance in an ArrayList that is in the class? It has to be done in the constructor (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

Given a class like the this:

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private int pages;
    private static ArrayList<Book> ArrayBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Book(String titl, int page){
        title=titl;
        pages=page;
    }
}
```

How can I keep a reference to every Book in the List, in a way that doesn't require any special calls - ie done automatically by the constructor.

Also, the List should have a max size of 20 books; if the user attempts to create the 21st book, he shouldn't be able to.

Can anyone figure out a way to implement it?

Comment: No need for arraylist,simply use Book array[20];

Comment: Why does it have to happen in the constructor?

Comment: Make method called in constructor.. and add all the books of that is array then use for loop what is hard in that.. just use some of the brain logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the current object, you could use the `this` reference. So your constructor could look like this:

```
public Book(String title, int pages) {
    this.title = title; // avoid abbreviations like "titl"
    this.pages = pages; // or "page" just to avoid same variable names
    ArrayBooks.add(this); // add new Book instance into the list
}
```

To avoid more than 20 entries, you have to check the current amount of entries in the list:

```
public Book(String title, int pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.pages = pages;
    (if ArrayBooks.size < 20) {
        ArrayBooks.add(this); // add new Book instance into the list
    }
}
```

And I recommend to read the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). So `ArrayBooks` should be `arrayBooks`.

**Edit**

To prohibit more than 20 `Book` instances, you'll need a factory method that takes care about creating the instances for you:

```
public static Book create(final String title, final int pages) {
    if (ArrayBooks.size() < 20) {
        final Book instance = new Book(title, pages);
        ArrayBooks.add(instance);
        return instance;
    }
    return null;
}

private Book(String title, int pages) { // "hide" the constructor, so the user can't use this instead of the factory
    this.title = title;
    this.pages = pages;
}
```

You could also throw an exception in your constructor, but I personally don't like that. It is up to you, which way you take.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I have one more question: How can I actually NOT allow the user to create the 21st book? I thought about creating a destructor that destructs the instance in that way: if (condition) else (destruct)  Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: @RoyKaram There are no destructors in Java. To do what you want, you have to create a factory method. I'll update my answer to show you, how they look like.

Comment: @RoyKaram Throw an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Add `this` to the `List`, and throw an exception if the user attempts to create the 21st:

```
public class Book {
    private static final List<Book> books = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Book>());
    private String title;
    private int pages;

    public Book(String title, int pages) {
        if (books.size() == 20)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Maximum number of books reached");
        this.title = title;
        this.pages = pages;
        books.add(this);
    }
}
```

I've added a call to [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) to add simple thread safety to prevent the maximum from being exceeded due to race conditions.

Also note the change of the list type to `List<Book>` (from `ArrayList<Book>`) - see [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: I guess, you meant `books.size()` (you forgot the parenthesis)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use list because it's good in some parameter then array.

```
public Book (String titl, int page) {
    title = titl;
    pages = page;
    Arraylist.add(this); // add new Book in the list
}
```

For not giving more then 20

```
public Book (String titl, int page) {
    title = titl;
    pages = page;
    if (Arraylist.size() < 20) {
        Arraylist.add(this); // add new Book into the list
    }
}
```

Try to apply first your own logic.